# Classification report and Accuracy between two files

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm trying to do a Classification report between two files. The two have the same data but the test.csv doesn't have a Survived column. the problem is for Classification report what should write in y test because the in the test file the " Survived" is missing

here my code

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

train = pd.read_csv('..../titanic/train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('..../titanic/test.csv')
X = train.drop('Survived' , axis=1)
y = train['Survived']

logmodel = LogisticRegression()
logmodel.fit(X,y)
predictions = logmodel.predict(test)

rr = {'PassengerId':test['PassengerId'] , 'Survived' : predictions}
result = pd.DataFrame(rr)
print(classification_report('what sould i write',predictions))
```

and for Accuracy
if I write like this

```
logmodel.score(X ,y)
```

> 0.797979797979798

this answer is the accuracy for the model what i predicts?
Is that correct or incorrect

Comment: [that is correct](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.score)

Comment: Please see the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.score)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have answers for test dataset in kaggle - you should split your "train.csv" into two parts, "train" and "test" and check on your own test part, not the kaggle one.

Kaggle test.csv is used to make predictions and upload it to kaggle web site. You can't know right answer without uploading.

Comment: this should be a comment on the OP not an answer

Comment: why not? is there some rule on SO?

Comment: hi @IvanSalaryev thank you is very clear but i have a question how can i know what the accuracy for what i predicts

Comment: Try this: ```predictions = logmodel.predict(train)``` and   ```print(classification_report(y, predictions))```

Comment: it doesnt anwer the question it makes a comment about the question